# How to remove "Scrapbook Photos" from stock Gallery?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gallery

A folder named "Scrapbook Photos" appears in my gallery app, but whenever I try to delete it, it remains. It doesn't contain any items, trying to navigate into the folder simply redraws the main gallery screen.

How can I remove this nuisance?

[image: Gallery main page with Scrapbook Photos in lower right corner.]

Answer (score 5):

You can delete it at [picasaweb.google.com](http://picasaweb.google.com).  (Click on the album, and then use the 'Actions' dropdown list.)

Answer (score 2):

That is not an actual folder on the device. It's from your Google++account. It contains the pictures that are displayed next to your profile picture. If you don't have any, it will still show up on your device except it will be empty.

It cannot be removed.

Comment: Ah. Well that makes sense, since I just activated a Google+ account. I'm rather annoyed at how many tendrils Google+ has snaking their way through everything.

Comment: What's worse is that this folder shows up even if photo sync is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This, and any other, folder of this kind (added automatically to Gallery, without reference to local on-device folder) is always added from Picassa, even if you have never used that service. If you're using newer versions of Android (4.1+) such folders should be marked with small Picassa icon in the bottom-right corner, where you have standard folder icon for *yours* folders.

These folders are often not editable from the device. I.e. you're saying about deleting this folder over and over again, while I ended-up with more than five such *scrap* folders without any kind of option to delete either entire folder or any of its contents. What was even worse (and more frustrating) you can have such folders even, if you don't use particular service at all. For example I had a lot of such garbage folders though I haven't activated Google+ and I haven't uploaded anything to Picassa.

The only way to remove such folders is to login to on-line service, it belongs to (Google+, Picassa etc.) and remove it there. In my case, using Picassa (that I have never used before) and remove any garbage Google has automatically added there solved the problem. You should be able to achieve the same, once you login to Google+.

Alternatively, you can disable Photos sync at all, if this is an option for you. But I've heard reports, that this may not help at some certain situations, especially, when source for additional folders is not Picassa, but Google+ or similar service.

Answer (score -2):

I would find the folder through usb mode or a file system explorer such as [X-Plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en) and delete the folder manually. Then it should be removed from the Gallery.

Comment: adb would work too, if you like that sort of thing.

Comment: I have Astro and AndSMB but haven't managed to find a folder names "Scrapbook Photos"

Comment: i'd hook it up to your computer and do a search on the device.

Comment: and did you look manually or do a search?

Comment: I used Astro's search feature to look for files and folders from the root, including all subfolders. I'm starting to think this gallery album is not a folder but a remnant in a settings file of some sort.

Comment: in the gallery, does the folder have a small thumbnail that looks like this http://runwaymagazine.co/Email_Blast_Images/social_network_logos/picasa_logo.gif?

Comment: Your link doesn't work, but I'll infer from the URL that you mean the Picasa logo. There is no icon; most other albums have a folder icon. I'll update my question with an image.

Comment: @jlehenbauer: This is a _virtual_ folder, added from Google account (Google+, Picassa or similar service). You can't locate it or delete as it does not exists on device, it has no reference or connection to any existing on-device folder and will most likely be recreated, even if you manage somehow to delete it, until you won't delete it on-line in the service (Google+, Picassa etc.) to which it belongs to -- see my answer.